Xcode hang risk warnings
I am puzzled by a deluge of warnings in Xcode 15 like:

This code path does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues. Consider ways to optimize this code path

on code that seems perfectly innocuous, like:
class FileOrFolderCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var newBadge: UILabel!
    //...
    let emojiLabelInitialFontSize: CGFloat = 64 // <-- flagged as potential hang risk
    //...
    var isNew = false { // <-- potential hang risk
        didSet {
            newBadge.isHidden = !isNew
        }
    }
//...
}

There is no I/O that I can see in my code. What are those warnings all about? Can anybody offer insights on how to address this? This was not happening in Xcode 14.

The above, alone, is obviously insufficient to manifest the problem. So, I might suggest that you create a blank project and see what you must add from your project to it in order to manifest the problem. Alternatively, you can approach the problem from the other direction: Create a copy of your project and start ripping out things, one-by-one, and identify out at what point the problem goes away. Either way, he’ll end up with a reproducible example of the problem. Only then will be able to help you.

Thanks, Rob, for your comment. I was primarly wondering if anyone had seen anything like it. Judging from how long the question has been up. nobody has. As a matter of fact, there isn't really a whole lot more to show, it is just initalizing a silly CGFloat variable, which in fact does nothing else and, in my view, should not trigger warnings of any sort. I eventually decided not to waste any more time on this and go back to xCode 14, where the issue does not come up.

Your suggestion to try other versions of 15.x is good, and I will look into it. As for the need for a MRE, I see what you mean, but the example doesn't get any more minimal, and reproducibility may come down to some oddity of my installation, or a misconfiguration of some kind (and the fact that nobody seems to have similar complaints seems to point in that direction). As for the need to adopt v. 15, that's a well taken point, but right now it seems a lower priority item in comparison with other matters I need to address. In any case thanks for your suggestions, I do appreciate them.

Well, what do you know? Going back from 15.3 to 15.2 (which I hadn't previously tried, just jumped from 14.3 to 15.3) completely cured the problem. Go figure. If you'd like to give that as the answer. go ahead, and I will accept it and mark the question as resolved. It remains to be seen if getting 15.3 to work properly is merely a matter of reinstalling, but for now, just getting things to work on 15.2 has made my day. Thank you for all your suggestions.

I might advise trying Xcode 15.2. I’ve seen reports of version 15.3 introducing these sorts of issues (e.g., Firebase issue #12640, How to fix Firebase Analytics purple error, etc.). In your case, I am unsure whether this is a false-positive or just a misidentification of where the hang risk rests.
As an aside, I’ve experienced other issues in 15.3, too (e.g., sendability false-positives, SwiftData’s ModelActor not actually moving to the actor’s context, etc.). That’s another argument for considering using 15.2.

FWIW, Xcode is identifying (correctly or not) a potential/theoretical hang. You might want to double-check and see if you can manifest a hang. See this answer, in which I discuss using Instruments’ “Time Profiler” template and “Hangs” tool to identify hangs. You might also want to change the “Hangs” tools setting to “Include All Potential Interaction Delays”. If your code is manifesting a hang, this will help you identify the actual culprit, if any.

As an aside, (and at the risk of sounding like a broken record) it would be very helpful to identify what precisely in your project (assuming it is not just Firebase) is leading to this error, as the snippet in the question is undoubtedly insufficient. The more feedback we can offer, the more likely that they will address it.

The Xcode 15.3 release notes says

Thread Performance Checker emits a new category of runtime issues called “Known Hangs” which shows developers where in their code hangs are known to affect users of their apps. (102045928)

So, if you are receiving false-positive of “Known Hangs” in Xcode 15.3, you might simply turn off the “Thread Performance Checker” in your scheme diagnostic settings. That may avoid producing these warnings.

For what is worth, I have tested and time-profiled the app in its current (unfinished) state, on multiple devices and simulators, for days on end, with and without restarts of application or devices/simulators, not experiencing a single hang. I have seen (and solved) resource leaks that Instruments has helped me sort out, but not a single threading-related problem. As for Firebase, I don't use it, as the app is almost entirely local in nature, and whatever network activity there is, it is accomplished by leveraging the iOS Files app and extending the app's sandbox to smb mounts.

When I have the time to re-download and install 15.3, I will try again and see if the warnings reappear, and report my experience.
